# Which CD Drive is used during boot if have multiple drives

Tags: optical-drive

I have 7 CD Drives attached to my computer. Now i want to install Linux on computer.

But i am not sure which drive is used when i boot.

I tried once putting in any drive.

The Linux starts but after sometime it says there is Ubuntu Live CD present.

I tried pn computer with one drive and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be in your BIOS: depending on your motherboard manufacturer, there are many ways to get to that. You should look for something along the lines of `Press F2 to enter Setup` on the initial bootscreen of your computer.

In the BIOS, you'll be able to select which drive your computer will boot from, this is usually found in the Boot menu under something like `Boot Disk Priority`--again, this varies depending on your motherboard's manufacturer.

Comment: The problem is i have 7 drives and same name appears in bios , so i don't know which drive is which

Comment: A quick an' dirty solution would be to unplug all but one.

Comment: well i have joined them after lot of trouble to keep them working so i can't take that risk.

The other solution i think is having different boot cds in all drives and see which one is selected in bios

Comment: If your motherboard supports it, you could install Ubuntu on a USB flash drive and boot from that. UNetBootIn has all the tools for that and will run on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Which drive is used depends on your bios settings.

I assume you wanted to install Ubuntu? If you PC showed you the Ubuntu Live CD Desktop, then you already found the right drive. The Ubuntu installation CD boots a "live" system to let you try out Ubuntu before installation.

AFAIK you will find a shortcut to the installation program that lets you install ubuntu.